# What are your "must-have" MacPorts?

Tags: macos, macports

I hate to be all cliché with yet another "best [something]" question, but I am genuinely interested in what you most often install with MacPorts. When you get a new Mac, which ports do you first install?

So far, I've installed **wget** and **watch**, since I find those to be very useful on Linux machines. I also installed **wine** and **winetricks** to run a Windows program or two. And earlier today I started playing with Scala, so I installed the **scala28** port.

*Tip: to see your installed ports, use the `port installed` command.*

Comment: This should be made into community wiki rather than simply closed.

Comment: @Phillip agreed, the question may bring interesting *undiscovered* stuff (as much as *other* ‘best’ questions).

Comment: This kind of poll would work much better with a "one per answer" rule, though.

Comment: This question is being closed due to lack of maintenance. Please vote to reopen or ask on [meta] if it's not clear how this can be kept current by editing and community care.

Comment: @bmike I don't understand - will it somehow be better maintained in a closed state, or are you "giving up" on it? (if the latter, why not just delete it then?) As a fellow mod, I would have thought community wiki would be enough.

Comment: Non-trusted users aren't seeing the "broken windows" that we as moderators do (by design). If you'd like a discussion, please ask on [meta] and we can go into details on what we're doing / why / and how this question fits into our process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just compile from source, since all of the important programs build easily on Mac OS X these days. Here's a great [article on the advantages of building your own stuff](http://hivelogic.com/articles/using_usr_local) vs. using package managers.

Having said that, here's my quick list:

- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [GNU Privacy
  Guard 1.4.x](http://www.gnupg.org/)
- [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)
- [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/) Best directions I've seen for building 32 or 64-bit MySQL on Mac OS X:
  [DIYMacServer](http://diymacserver.com/installing-mysql/)

Comment: I couldn't find anything specific in that article about it being better than using package managers... what's the gist? :P

Comment: @calavera that may turn into a flame-war between Gentoo LInux users trying to justify why they spend 30 hours compiling the last line of code of their *entire* OS and RedHat users telling them that they *simply use rpm*. :)

Answer (score 11):

This is my essential list, in the order that I install them.

- arping
- watch
- wireshark
- figlet
- git
- gnupg
- ipcalc
- lynx +ssl
- minicom
- mtr
- ncftp
- nmap
- pstree
- pwgen
- p0f
- ssldump
- stunnel
- tcpflow
- unrar
- w3m
- wget

Answer (score 7):

In no particular order:

- git - git
- signing-party - GnuPG key signing utils, pulls in GnuPG as well
- ntop - A Unix tool that shows the network usage, similar to what the popular top Unix command does.
- sslscan - sslscan queries SSL services, such as HTTPS, in order to determine the ciphers that are supported
- watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen
- nmap - Network port scan to see what ports are open
- coreutils GNU coreutils. Includes gnu versions of basic unix commands, including "color ls" (gls)
- pstree - Process tree listing
- tcping - tcp
  based network connectivity checker
  (like ping but with TCP for when ICMP
  is blocked)
- wget - non-interactive
  network downloader. Supports http,
  https and ftp
- apg - Automated Password Generator - toolset for generating random passwords

Answer (score 4):

First thing I do is update to the latest bash version... then I usually grab some updated versions of utilities:

- grep
- sudo
- man
- info (although i had to go with the fink version for this, macports is bugged)
- gdiff

Then on to my development tools like subversion, git, vim, macvim, python3, etc.  I heart MacPorts :P

Comment: It's now time to try out `zsh` too. +[oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)

Comment: @slomojo: that looks pretty cool, i might have to try it out

Comment: instead of ~~oh-my-zsh~~, try prezto instead

Answer (score 3):

- bash
- bash-completion (very important)
- nmap
- file

Comment: +1 for bash-completion. I was wanting something like that.

Answer (score 3):

- **wget** : is command-line that allow me to retrieve any file using HTTP, HTTPS and FTP.
- **tree** : displays a tree-view of my directories & files, with deep-level option.

You can participate with your MacPorts by typing :

> `port installed requested`

Answer (score 2):

The [Google CL tools](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) are cool and useful (I do a lot with Docs).

Answer (score 1):

For PHP web development:

- coreutils
- kcachegrind
- git
- svn